# Error while installing numpy in alpine image

Tags: numpy, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Error :

> ERROR: Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2u_c2pqi/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gfsn5nsl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-2u_c2pqi/numpy/

This is the error I am getting in my travis build of my dockerfile.

```
RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
 24     && apk --no-cache --update-cache add postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers g++ gfortran py-pip build-base bash libpng-dev openblas-dev w    get freetype-dev gcc \
 25     && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
 26     && pip3 install setuptools wheel \
 27     && pip3 install numpy pyyaml`
```

I am installing numpy using the above commands

Answer (score 0):

Some issues have been found in your `Dockerfile`:

1. `python3-dev` and `py3-pip` packages should be installed to install `numpy`.
2. `g++` already has `gcc` and `musl-dev` in dependencies, so we can simplify a package list.

The final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
     && apk --no-cache --update-cache add postgresql-dev g++ linux-headers gfortran build-base bash libpng-dev openblas-dev wget freetype-dev python3-dev py3-pip \
     && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
     && pip3 install setuptools wheel \
     && pip3 install numpy pyyaml
```